# Can I replace "long" with "distant"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

If two paths are of the **same length**, they are **equally long**. But then, if they're of the **same distance**, they are **equally... distant**?

It doesn't sound at all right and I strongly suspect that it's just not a case when a switcharoo between nouns allows for the equivalent on the related adjectives. In my ears, the second version sounds like they are equally distant **from each other**, without the actual requirement of being equally long. Then again, that statement makes no sense because two objects are always equally distant from each other (physical ones, at least).

Which is it?

Comment: Are you asking "What is the difference in meaning between length and distance? I live in Bristol; Wolverhampton and Coventry are both the same distance from me, 80 miles.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm not sure if I got your example right. My question is about finding a synonym noun-wise and check if the synonyms on the related adjectives are still valid.

Comment: @KonradViltersten If they are equally long, their length from start to finish is the same. If they are equally distant, they are equally distant from a specified point regardless of their length. Two objects are indeed always equally distant from each other as long as they are stationary (which often they are not).

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten - synonym for what?

Comment: "they're of the same distance"... length is a property of an object, whereas distance is measured in relation to another object.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey A bit off-questions main trail, perhaps, but is it really a requirement that two objects are stationary for their distance to each other to be the same? If they move, isn't the distance from A to B and from B to A always the same? (It may differ from a previous distance but at any given point, it's the same, right? At least for **physical** objects.)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think that the main question was answered below already (based on your formulation, kind of). I suspect that it was me complicating something rather plain. Hence the weirdness of my formulation. Sorry.   :)

Comment: @Konrad Viltersetn "If they move, isn't the distance from A to B and from B to A always the same?" Yes, of course this must necessarily be the case. It is a trivial and obvious observation.

Comment: @Ronald Sole: "Two objects are indeed always equally distant from each other as long as they are stationary (which often they are not)." Any two objects, moving or stationary, are always "equally distant" from each other. There is only one distance.

Comment: You can get so hung up on language that you forget common sense. Happens with programming languages too. A lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Harvey's comment pretty much says it all:

> **length** is a property of an object, whereas **distance** is measured in relation to another object

If two paths have the same length, then they are equally long.  If they have the same distance *from start to finish*, then they are also equally long.  You can't use *distance* or *distant* without at least implying some reference points, as explained in [the definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/distance).

> **The road** from the highway to the ranch house **is 4 miles long**
>
> The distance **from the ranch to the highway** is 4 miles.

Or, related to your example:

> As the crow flies, **the distance** from Red's house to her Granny's house **is only a few miles**, and both paths to get there **are of the same length**.  However, one path goes up a steep and treacherous stone staircase carved into the side of a mountain, while the other wanders through a wolf-infested forest.